# PHP associative array with non-unique keys

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Struggling with concept of an associative array that maps userIDs to partIDs and re-order quantity for the part.

We have bunch of parts that I need to re-order, but I must keep track of which user needs what parts re-purchased for them. The list of UserIDs comes from one table, then the inventory_used comes from another table.

Suppose a list like this:

**Example One:**

```
UserID   PartID   Qty_Used
    1       3       2
    1       4       7
    2       1       4
    2       4       3
    3       3       5
```

After creating an array with the above information, I must create a re-order form (table) for the parts. Therefore, ignoring the userID, group them by the partID, and sum up the total Qty (per part). The re-order table should look something like this:

**Example Two:**

```
PartID      Qty_to_Reorder
    1        4
    3        7
    4       10
```

I know I'm going to take a ton of downvotes for failing to show code, but I can't wrap my mind around this seemingly simple problem. (This is for my office, not a school project).

How do I:

(1) Structure the first array (what would the loop to create it look like?), and then

(2) Loop through that array to summarize/group `partIDs => Qty` for re-order report, as per 2nd example above?

---

For the first loop, i was thinking of something like this:

```
Loop through UserIDs {
    Loop through PartIDs {
        $arrReorder[UserID][PartID] = Qty_Used;
    }
}
```

Is that correct? How would I loop through $arrReorder to sum-up the qty used for each partID, and get the re-order report (example 2)?

Comment: Do it in the query:  `SELECT PartID, SUM(Qty_to_Reorder) as Total FROM table  GROUP BY PartID`

Comment: How do you want to restructure the data from *Example One*? I assume that's what you are trying to do?

Comment: How can you know how many units of item #5 have been used by user #1, unless the inventory has the user information? I mean, if the inventory table only reports "Part 5: used 12 pieces", one can't know how many were used by one user and how many by another.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUM(Qty_Used) AS total FROM mytable WHERE PartID=3

PS: Using PHP

```
<?php
    $data = array();
    $data[] = array("UserID" => 1, "PartID" => 3, "Qty_Used" => 2);
    $data[] = array("UserID" => 1, "PartID" => 4, "Qty_Used" => 7);
    $data[] = array("UserID" => 2, "PartID" => 1, "Qty_Used" => 4);
    $data[] = array("UserID" => 2, "PartID" => 4, "Qty_Used" => 3);
    $data[] = array("UserID" => 3, "PartID" => 3, "Qty_Used" => 5);

    $PartID = 3;
    $sum = 0;

    foreach ($data as $arr) {

        if ($arr['PartID'] == $PartID)
            $sum += $arr['Qty_Used'];
    }

    echo $PartID."\t".$sum."\r\n";
?>
```

Comment: The OP doesn't actually mention MySQL use anywhere. Please elaborate on your answer

Comment: He did not say about mysql but I believe that these data are coming from a database and possibly mysql.

Comment: Yes, MySQL - it's PHP, so reasonable assumption +1  (Adding to OP)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have a key and value where the value can be another array.  Determine what is the key value.

I am assuming you have users consuming parts and you have to re-order the parts from your supplier. No where the user is a customer and the user has a auto re-order policy.

What triggers a reorder?  If re-order quantity is 10 and user uses 1, there should be nine in stock.

Create the partsUsed array elements, This is a bit tricky:

```
$partsUsed[$part][] = array($qtyUsed,$user);
```

The reason the empty brackets `[]` is there is to allow duplicate part numbers in the parts used, and still key part as the key.

The value is an array to key the association between user and parts.

what you end up with is a sequentially numbered secondary key where the value is just a throw away, but allows duplicate part numbers.

```
 $partsUsed[3][] = array(2,1);
 $partsUsed[4][] = array(7,1);
 $partsUsed[1][] = array(4,2);
 $partsUsed[4][] = array(3,2);
 $partsUsed[3][] = array(5,5);
 ksort($partsUsed);  // sorts key on part number
 var_export($partsUsed);
```

Result array (var_export):
    array (
      1 => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          0 => 4,
          1 => 2,
        ),
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          0 => 2, 
          1 => 1,
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          0 => 5,
          1 => 5,
        ),
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          0 => 7,
          1 => 1,
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          0 => 3,
          1 => 2,
        ),
      ),
    )

Notice part 3 and 4 have two arrays.

```
$reorder[1] = 4 ;
$reorder[2] = 7 ;
$reorder[4] = 10 ;
var_export($reorder);
```

Result array:

```
array (
  1 => 4,
  2 => 7,
  4 => 10,
)
```

Now not sure how to determine what gets reordered and how many.
I'll show how to get the values:

```
foreach($partsUsed as $part => $value){
  foreach($value as $k => $v){
    echo "Part $part: Qty:$v[0] User:$v[1]\n";
    $qtyUsed[$part] += $v[1];
  }
}
var_export($qtyUsed);
```

Outputs:

```
Part 1: Qty:4 User:2
Part 3: Qty:2 User:1
Part 3: Qty:5 User:3
Part 4: Qty:7 User:1
Part 4: Qty:3 User:2
```

$qtyUsed

```
array (
  1 => 2,
  3 => 4,
  4 => 3,
)

foreach ($qtyUsed as $part => $qty){
    $order[$part] = $reorder[$part]; 
}
var_export($order);
```

Result $order:

```
array (
  1 => 4,
  3 => 7,
  4 => 10,
)
```